# Bundler doesn't load gem in production rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm having a problem where a single gem is not being loaded by bundler in a rails app, but only in production - there's no problem using the gem in development mode.

The gem is [country_select](https://rubygems.org/gems/country_select), and we've tried it with version 1.1.3 and the github repository. The app is using rails 3.2.11.

#### Proof that the gem exists on the server

The gem is successfully installed by bundler in the production environment:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle install
...
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using country_select (1.1.3)
Using daemons (1.1.9)
...
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /home/deploy/rails-app/shared/bundle
```

The gem appears in the shared gem directory that bundler installs to:

```
$ ls -al /home/deploy/rails-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ | grep country
drwxrwxr-x  3 deploy deploy 4096 Apr  3 08:49 country_select-1.1.3
```

And the gem is loaded when starting rails from the console:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production script/rails c
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):002:0> Gem.loaded_specs.keys.grep /country/
=> ["country_select"]
```

#### However...

That same check for the `country_select` gem in the rails app fails. For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter do
    raise Gem.loaded_specs.keys.grep(/country/).inspect
  end

  #...
end
```

Spits out `[]` - i.e. the gem is not loaded. Plus, parts of the application that rely on the gem fail as a result of it not existing.

### And finally, the question

Simply adding a `require 'country_select'` somewhere in the startup means that the gem gets loaded, and the app works. But why isn't bundler doing it with that particular gem, despite the fact that it installs it and adds it to the app's gem directory?

#### More info about the production environment:

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.18.18 (stable)...
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
1.8.25
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.3.2
```

### Update: 5th April 2013

The problem seems to have *"gone away"*. After a couple of redeployments, it appears to be working. This is in spite of the fact that the country_select gem hasn't been changed, which is **very** odd. I'm still looking into exactly what has changed in that time, but I'm puzzled.

Comment: Can you link us to your Gemfile?

Comment: @RyanAngilly sure, [here's the Gemfile](http://pastie.org/private/emprtlgcdarbmp7wkve6g)

Comment: I always put require somewhere in my code at startup - is this not a common practice?

Comment: @lightswitch05 rails 3 does this by default if using bundler, in *config/application.rb*. But it would be required if not using bundler, or earlier rails versions.

Comment: I have this problem and its placed my rails app in 500 only mode in production...

Did you do anything to make it go away? or did bundler just start doing its job after a couple of days?

Comment: @Arcath I didn't do anything to fix it - I literally just redeployed a couple of times and it seemed to fix itself. Strange!

Comment: @joonty figured it out, don't know if you where having the same cause but I use GOD which had expanded the path to my application from /foo/bar/current/ to /foo/bar/releases/xx/ when it restarted unicorn it used /foo/bar/releases/xx instead of /foo/bar/releases/yy which is where the /foo/bar/current symlink pointed too. I'd never had an issue before with the loading because the Gemfile hadn't changed since xx.

Comment: @Arcath interesting, thanks for the feedback. I'll keep an eye out!

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/rails c
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't help - the gem *is* loaded from the console, but not from the web app. `bundle exec` solves the problem of  having multiple versions of a gem installed, but that's not the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

I have an app using the same versions and I don't need to require the gem in dev or production. I also tried with your `before_filter` and got `["country_select"]` as expected. So the problem isn't with the gem.

I think you're either monkeying around with the loaded gems in initialization somewhere (unlikely) or there's something going wrong with your setup around the server. Are you starting the server with `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/rails server`? Can you check the gem path being used by the server includes the shared gem path you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not starting the server that way, as I'm using thin as a proxy with Nginx as the web server. Also, I checked the GEM_PATH environment variable but it appears that bundler doesn't use that - it uses what's in *.bundle/config*, which was the correct shared directory. I've discovered something else, see my edit on the original question.